# Standard "Android More Settings" transition

Tags: android

Does anyone know where in `http://androidxref.com` I can find the transition config for this "settings more" horizontal transition? Details below:

In androidxref.com I found all the standard transition configurations:

- Standard Android navigation transition when opening an Activity - http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/anim/activity_open_enter.xml

  ```
  transitionSpec: {
      duration: 350,
      easing: Easing.out(Easing.poly(5)), // decelerate
      timing: Animated.timing,
  },
  ```
- Standard Android navigation transition when closing an Activity - http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/anim/activity_close_exit.xml

  ```
  transitionSpec: {
      duration: 230,
      easing: Easing.in(Easing.poly(4)), // accelerate
      timing: Animated.timing,
  },
  ```

However I cannot find the "Standard Android More Settings" transition config which we see in settings page as a horizontal translate. And previous screen gets a black dimmer on it.

#### Here is a screen recording of it:

- Here is HD - https://gfycat.com/ShyFlusteredChanticleer
- Here is gif:

  [image]

#### Here it is slowed down by 4x:

- Here is HD - https://gfycat.com/SecondhandIcyIberianemeraldlizard
- Here is gif:

  [image]

Does anyone know where in `http://androidxref.com` I can find the config for this settings transition?